# SQL Server table row

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, datatable

Just a SQL Server 2008 generic question, I have a table that has around 15 columns and they are string, int and bool types only, I am not storing any binary data, and I have auto generated PK column "ID" with @@IDENTITY enabled to generate unique ID on every entry, my question is that a table like this how many rows can have, is there any row limitation in SQL Server table?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are limits defined in ["Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx#Engine) on MSDN

Some relevant ones

- 1024 columns per standard table
- Rows per table: Limited by available storage
- Bytes per row: 8060 (except for row overflow data)

Basically, don't worry...

Comment: thanks, just a follow up question, do you know what can happen if my ID column reached at very last @@IDENTITY number?

Comment: @NazoTajrian: an error. However, using bigint (signed 64 bit integer) you have around a range of 10^38 rows. int (signed 32 bit integer) is 4.2 billion. Plenty of scope.